# AsyncApex Scenarios

Tags: apex, batch, future, asynchronous

I am writing a few Ques for which i have found conflicting answers on Internet. Also I have written my Answers after researching on Internet, but wasnt 100% sure, hence posting these here to clear fully.

Please let me know if those are correct.

If there any exceptions to each scenario, do let me know those as well.

---

1. `Future to Future method calling?` -> Cant be done.
2. `Pass Non-Primitive data type to Future method?` -> Cant be done. The alternative is to use Queueable. The best practice is to pass List of ID's to the future method.
3. `Call Batch from Queueable & vice versa?` -> Yes this is possible. Through Execute() method.
4. `Call Batch or Queueable from Future & vice versa?` -> Cant be done. No Async can be called from Future. Nor any Async can call Future.
5. `Mandatory to write all methods of Batch Class?` -> Yes. As they all are part of the Interface we implement.
6. `50K records process at one time in DML?` ->

   a. If 50000, through normal apex processing can be done, but not ideal. Alternate is Batch.

   b. If its 50001, then only option is Batch.

Comment: I did not downvote this question, but I believe it's attracting downvotes and close votes because it doesn't quite fit the SFSE format. We look for one specific technical question per post. "Is X correct?" for one X _may_ work here if you share the work or research you've done to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct.
2. Correct. In addition, you can also pass collections of primitives.
3. Correct. Note that you're limited to just one call, rather than the 50 you'd get in synchronous code.
4. Incorrect. You are allowed to call a (1) Queueable in a future method. You're also allowed to call (1) future method in other asynchronous code.
5. Correct. Note that this isn't specifically limited to Batchable. All interfaces must have all of their interface methods implemented in the class that implements that interface.
6. Incorrect. You are allowed only 10,000 records in direct DML per transaction. Note that Batchable is usually ideal for larger sets of data, but it is also possible to use Queueable, and simply have the Queueable chain itself as necessary.

Comment: N.B #4 - can also call schedulable from future

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for replying.Very helpful. Other people seem to be more interested in downvoting & discourage people rather than answer questions & share knowledge.